# Android webview loading dialog

Tags: android, dialog, webview, loading

I'm trying to implement a loading dialog in my webview application but whatever I do it just won't work.

What I want is the following, everytime someone clicks a link in the webview the loading dialog has to popup like this:

[image: loading dialog]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://thedevelopersinfo.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/without_title4.png?w=600))</sub>

And when the loading is done it has to disappear. Can anyone show me how to do it in my own source? I've tried a lot of things but there's always an issue so I really don't know how to.

This is my WebviewActivity:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebviewActivity extends MainActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);        
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }   

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if ( isOnline() == true )
            myWebView.loadUrl(webLink);
        else if ( isOnline() == false )
            showNoConnectionDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Use Asynchronous task for this... don't do custom progress dialog. Refer this link http://as400samplecode.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-asynctask-httpclient-with.html

Comment: Okay, but I'm not really into that so I don't know how I can archieve that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my final solution:

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            progressDialog.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;                
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to override the WebViewClient like this,

```
      webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

                progressDialog.cancel();


            }
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                progressDialog.show();
            }
      });

webview.loadUrl(TwitterUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible with WebChromeClient. It does worked for me.

Code snippet :

```
progressDialog.show(); // Add before page load
webView.setWebChromeClient(new HelpWebChromeClient());
private class HelpWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
   @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
     if(newProgress == 100)
        progressDialog.dismiss();
     }
 }
```